# clojurescript / twitter bootstrap tooltip jayq

Tags: clojurescript

when i trie to set a twitter bootstrap tooltip on a dom element

```
(.tooltip $( :#someid) (clj->js {:placement :left}))
```

I get

```
> Uncaught TypeError: Object function (sel, var_args) {
>     var p__9921 = null;
>     if(goog.isDef(var_args)) {
>       p__9921 = cljs.core.array_seq(Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 1), 0)
>     }
>     return $__delegate.call(this, sel, p__9921)   } has no method 'tooltip' clusty.js:23013 (anonymous function)
```

I am not using any advanced optimization's and don't have issues using jayq with other libs like datatables...

What am i missing?

Thanks

Comment: It looks like you've transposed the dollar sign and open paren.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you've transposed the dollar sign and open paren.

```
(.tooltip ($ :#someid) (clj->js {:placement :left}))
```

(reposting Kevin's comment here so that question can be closed)